# Chart that Dynamically References Data that is Constantly Overwritten

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts, alteryx

I have an Alteryx workflow that will output to different tabs in an excel workbook. These tabs will essentially be deleted and a new tab will take its place with the most current outputted information once the workflow is ran.

I would like to automate the plotting of this data set with a properly configured chart in another tab that dynamically references the data found in the tabs that are being updated from running the Alteryx workflow.

Essentially, once the data set updates, the chart will reflect these changes.

How can this be done? Is VBA required?

EDIT: More information

- There are 2 tabs that Alteryx will output to. There will be no additional tabs created other than the 2 tabs.
- When the Alteryx workflow is ran to update the data, each tab is deleted and recreated with the updated information
- Workbook is closed when Alteryx is ran
- The information from each tab is plotted separately

I was thinking that either powerquery (no experience with) or VBA could solve this issue. My vision of the solution would be a macro that is ran everytime the data is updated to plot the data.

Comment: VBA will almost certainly be required. How many "new data" tabs will be created that will contain the most recent data? Is the data from all the new tabs condensed into a single chart (if there is more than one new tab)? Is the workbook open the entire time the Alteryx workflow is running, or is the workbook only opened after the workflow completes? Is it an existing workbook or is a new workbook created each time the workflow executes? Bottom line is that, yes, a chart can be created automatically from your new data but there are lots of questions to answer to build the solution.

Comment: @PeterT, Sorry for late response, please see my edits in my post. Someone suggested that I could use powerquery on another forum. Will both VBA and powerquery work? Which one would be easier and more efficient? Thanks.